# Postfix reject unknown local recipients

Tags: linux, postfix, restrictions

I have a problem with backscatter. Spammers send emails to non existent username @ existent domain hosted on my server. I am trying to abort the session instead of sending bounce messages back to forged sender addresses. I tried adding reject_unverified_recipient, but that doesn't seem to work.

When I check mailq, I can see many stuck "user doesn't exist" bounce emails from MAILER_DAEMON to non existent recipients.

Here is my postconf -n

```
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
config_directory = /etc/postfix
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
mailbox_size_limit = 0
message_size_limit = 102400000
milter_default_action = accept
milter_protocol = 2
mydestination = localhost
myhostname = domain.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8
non_smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relay_domains =
relayhost =
resolve_numeric_domain = yes
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination, reject_unknown_recipient_domain, reject_unverified_recipient, permit_auth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_tls_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/domain.com.chain.crt
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/domain.com.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/domain.com.key
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
virtual_alias_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/sqlconf/virtual_alias_domains.cf
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/sqlconf/virtual_mailbox_maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/sqlconf/mydestination.cf
virtual_transport = dovecot
```

This is the master.cf file

```
smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
  -o content_filter=spamassassin
  -o receive_override_options=no_header_body_checks,no_unknown_recipient_checks,no_milters
smtps     inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
  -o content_filter=checkhook
  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
dovecot   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail:vmail argv=/usr/lib/dovecot/deliver -f ${sender} -d ${recipient}
pickup    unix  n       -       -       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       -       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
#qmgr     unix  n       -       n       300     1       oqmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       -       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       -       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       -       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       -       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
showq     unix  n       -       -       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       -       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       -       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       -       -       1       scache
maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix  -       n       n       -       2       pipe
  flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
mailman   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py
  ${nexthop} ${user}
spamassassin unix -     n       n       -       -       pipe
  user=spamfilter argv=/usr/bin/spamc -f -e /usr/sbin/sendmail -oi -f ${sender} ${recipient}
checkhook unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  user=www-data argv=/etc/postfix/scripts/send ${sender} ${recipient}
```

Here are some logs that were made when I tried to send to invalid local recipient.

```
Jan 22 19:09:34 ip-12345 postfix/qmgr[19938]: CF96B20013B: from=<invalid@sender.ocm>, size=249, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jan 22 19:09:35 ip-12345 postfix/pickup[19939]: 982D320013D: uid=5007 from=<invalid@sender.ocm>
Jan 22 19:09:35 ip-12345 postfix/pipe[21485]: CF96B20013B: to=<nonexistentx@localdomain.com>, relay=spamassassin, delay=18, delays=16/0/0/1.2, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered via spamassassin service)                           
Jan 22 19:09:35 ip-12345 postfix/qmgr[19938]: CF96B20013B: removed
Jan 22 19:09:35 ip-12345 postfix/cleanup[21477]: 982D320013D: message-id=<20170122190935.982D320013D@maindomain.com>
Jan 22 19:09:35 ip-12345 postfix/qmgr[19938]: 982D320013D: from=<invalid@sender.ocm>, size=1333, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jan 22 19:09:35 ip-12345 dovecot: auth: Debug: master in: USER#0111#011nonexistentx@localdomain.com#011service=lda
Jan 22 19:09:35 ip-12345 dovecot: auth-worker(14636): Debug: sql(nonexistentx@localdomain.com): SELECT '/var/vmail/nonexistentx@localdomain.com' as home, 'vmail' as uid, 'vmail' as gid, concat('*:storage=', quota_kb) AS quota_rule, concat('*:messages=', quota_msg) AS quota_rule2 FROM users WHERE username = 'nonexistentx' AND domain = 'localdomain.com' and active=1                          
Jan 22 19:09:35 ip-12345 dovecot: auth-worker(14636): sql(nonexistentx@localdomain.com): unknown user                                                  
Jan 22 19:09:35 ip-12345 dovecot: auth: Debug: userdb out: NOTFOUND#0111       
Jan 22 19:09:35 ip-12345 postfix/pipe[21400]: 982D320013D: to=<nonexistentx@localdomain.com>, relay=dovecot, delay=0.07, delays=0.05/0/0/0.02, dsn=5.1.1, status=bounced (user unknown)                                              
Jan 22 19:09:35 ip-12345 postfix/cleanup[21396]: A8B0720013C: message-id=<20170122190935.A8B0720013C@maindomain.com>
Jan 22 19:09:35 ip-12345 postfix/bounce[21474]: 982D320013D: sender non-delivery notification: A8B0720013C                                                   
Jan 22 19:09:35 ip-12345 postfix/qmgr[19938]: A8B0720013C: from=<>, size=3394, nrcpt=1 (queue active)                                                  
Jan 22 19:09:35 ip-12345 postfix/qmgr[19938]: 982D320013D: removed      
Jan 22 19:09:35 ip-12345 postfix/smtp[21496]: A8B0720013C: to=<invalid@sender.ocm>, relay=none, delay=0.03, delays=0/0.01/0.02/0, dsn=5.4.4, status=bounced (Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=sender.ocm type=A: Host not found)                                                              
Jan 22 19:09:35 ip-12345 postfix/qmgr[19938]: A8B0720013C: removed
```

Comment: you need to point local_recipient_maps to your dovecot users, the reject_unverified_recipient

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can check the solutions from the [Postfix Backscatter Howto](http://www.postfix.org/BACKSCATTER_README.html).

And if you really want to get rid of persistent backscatter/spammers, you might want to implement a [fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org) policy combined with [postscreen](http://www.postfix.org/POSTSCREEN_README.html). Postscreen alone eliminates practically all the spammers, with minimal resource usage, and it's very easy to implement, since it's already part of postfix.

Answer (score -1):

You could either disable bounce in master.cf

```
bounce    unix  -       -       -       -       0       discard
```

Or configure an spf check (there are modules in perl and python or with amavis/spamassassin) to discard messages that do not pass spf checks and not generate the bounce for ilegal sources, but still being able to notify legal mail sources (full quotas, message size over limit, old addresses that are not longer attended, etc)

Comment: um,  how would spf checks help exactly?